# RecyclerView Item Swipe to Dismiss gets stuck sometimes

Tags: android-recyclerview, ezswipecontroller

I am working on RecyclerView swipe to show an action button behind list items and my RecyclerView is in a fragment with Bottom Navigation and everything is going well but sometimes swipe stops and gets stuck so I can't completely swipe the item. I need your help with this. My codes:

The code in main activity:

```java
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchhelper = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeController);
itemTouchhelper.attachToRecyclerView(movelistview);

movelistview.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        swipeController.onDraw(c,"action");
    }
});
```

The code in the Swipe Controller class:

```java
public class SwipeController extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private static final float buttonWidth = 200;
    private boolean swipeBack = false;
    private ButtonsState buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.GONE;
    private RectF buttonInstance = null;
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder currentItemViewHolder = null;
    private SwipeControllerActions buttonsActions = null;

    public SwipeController(SwipeControllerActions buttonsActions) {
        this.buttonsActions = buttonsActions;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return makeMovementFlags(0, LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    }

    @Override
    public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
        if (swipeBack) {
            swipeBack = buttonShowedState != ButtonsState.GONE;
            return 0;
        }
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            if (buttonShowedState != ButtonsState.GONE) {
                // if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE) dX = Math.max(dX, buttonWidth);
                if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE)
                    dX = Math.min(dX, -buttonWidth);
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            } else {
                setTouchListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        }

        if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.GONE) {
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
        currentItemViewHolder = viewHolder;
    }

    private void setTouchListener(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final float dX, final float dY, final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                swipeBack = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
                if (swipeBack) {
                    if (dX < -buttonWidth) buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE;
                    //else if (dX > buttonWidth) buttonShowedState  = ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE;

                    if (buttonShowedState != ButtonsState.GONE) {
                        setTouchDownListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                        setItemsClickable(recyclerView, false);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTouchDownListener(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final float dX, final float dY, final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    setTouchUpListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTouchUpListener(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final float dX, final float dY, final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    SwipeController.super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, 0F, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    setItemsClickable(recyclerView, true);
                    swipeBack = false;

                    if (buttonsActions != null && buttonInstance != null && buttonInstance.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    /*if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {
                        buttonsActions.onLeftClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    }else*/
                        if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                            buttonsActions.onRightClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                    }
                    buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.GONE;
                    currentItemViewHolder = null;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setItemsClickable(RecyclerView recyclerView, boolean isClickable) {
        for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            recyclerView.getChildAt(i).setClickable(isClickable);
        }
    }

    private void drawButtons(Canvas c, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, String text) {
        float buttonWidthWithoutPadding = buttonWidth - 0;
        float corners = 0;

        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        Paint p = new Paint();
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        String button_text = "Report";

        if (position >= 0) {
            if (MainApplication.moves_list.get(position).getMove_userId().equals(MainApplication.user_id)) {
                button_text = "Delete";
            } else {
                button_text = "Report";
            }
        }

        RectF rightButton = new RectF(itemView.getRight() - buttonWidthWithoutPadding, itemView.getTop() + 0, itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom() - 0);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        c.drawRoundRect(rightButton, corners, corners, p);
        drawText(button_text, c, rightButton, p);

        buttonInstance = null;
        if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
            buttonInstance = rightButton;
        }
    }

    private void drawText(String text, Canvas c, RectF button, Paint p) {
        float textSize = 40;
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setTextSize(textSize);

        float textWidth = p.measureText(text);
        c.drawText(text, button.centerX() - (textWidth / 2), button.centerY() + (textSize / 2), p);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas c, String text) {
        if (currentItemViewHolder != null) {
            drawButtons(c, currentItemViewHolder, text);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. swipe button stuck in UI, Behind recyclerview. So here is the easy and best solution ever i found.

create new Function in SwipeViewController as below

```java
public void setSwipeBack()
{
    swipeBack = false;
    buttonShowedState = ButtonsStates.GONE;

}
```

and use this function in your fragment where your are filling data in the same recycler view.
as below

setSwipeBack();

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solution turned out to be easy.

This will happen when parent container will intercept your touch event. Any ViewGroup that overrides ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent) can do that (RecyclerView or ScrollView for instance).

And this will result in returning `ACTION_CANCEL` from your motionEvent when the `Y` value slightly changes, and sending touch events to parent view.

Proper way to deal with this is to call ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean) method on your parent view once you think you need to keep the motion event.

Here's a quick example (attemptClaimDrag() method is taken from android source code):

```java
/**
 * Tries to claim the user's drag motion, and requests disallowing any
 * ancestors from stealing events in the drag.
 */
private void attemptClaimDrag() {
    // parent = yourView.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
}
```

And in your onTouchEvent() or onTouch():

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (iWantToKeepThisEventForMyself(event)) {
            attemptClaimDrag();
        }
        //your logic here
    } else {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case you have to do this inside your onTouch() override.